# How to get song Length with MCI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mci

Try ro find song duration like HH:MM:SS for showing in my program.

Try to use

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
    private static extern long mciSendString(string strCommand,
        StringBuilder strReturn, int iReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);
```

with

```
public int CurrentTime()
    {
        MPlayerCommand = "status MediaFile length track number";
        error = mciSendString(MPlayerCommand, returnData, 128, IntPtr.Zero);
        return Convert.ToInt32(returnData.ToString());
    }
```

But as result get error - "incorrect input string"

Use for understanding [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As I understand for getting song length need to use command `status MediaFile length track number`, where `status` - main command, `MediaFile` - tell to use current opened MediaFile, `length track number` - requested parameter. Use this method only after opening file.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old question, but I think you've misread the documentation, `length track number` meant to be replaced by `length track 1`, `length track 2`, ... where `number` is the actual track # :)